# MySQL query for ranking by column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am running a query in php which gives me a table in this format:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Name               cc          Platform         Playcount      Date    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| The Godfather      IN           Web              20000            20140701 |
| The Godfather      IN           Mob              210            20140701 |
| The Godfather      US           Web              221            20140701  |
| The Godfather      US           Mob              1200            20140701 |
| Pulp Fiction      IN           Web              1300            20140701  |
| Pulp Fiction      IN           Mob              20            20140701  |
| Pulp Fiction      US           Web              222            20140701   |
| Pulp Fiction      US           Mob              100            20140701  |
| Fight Club      IN           Web              2002            20140701    |
| Fight Club      IN           Mob              2100            20140701    |
| Fight Club      US           Web              2           20140701     |
| Fight Club      US           Mob              1000            20140701    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The problem is, that I need to rank them by total playcount. That is , The Godfather clearly has the highest number of total playcount in this table. After ranking, I need to select the top 20 total playcount movies, and the corresponding 4 rows have to be entered into a separate table.

How can I do this ranking to get the total and then insert all four rows corresponding to that into a new table?

So, in this example table, if I want items having top 2 rank, I'll insert this in my table

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Name               cc          Platform         Playcount      Date    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| The Godfather      IN           Web              20000            20140701 |
| The Godfather      IN           Mob              210            20140701 |
| The Godfather      US           Web              221            20140701  |
| The Godfather      US           Mob              1200            20140701 |
| Fight Club      IN           Web              2002            20140701    |
| Fight Club      IN           Mob              2100            20140701    |
| Fight Club      US           Web              2           20140701     |
| Fight Club      US           Mob              1000            20140701    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you post your query

Comment: First, show your query if possible. Second, make a SQLfiddle @ sqlfiddle.com if possible. Lastly, I THINK I know what you are talking about, but it'd be great if you have a example of your desired result instead of simply text description.

Comment: I have added the result for rank < 2. Thanks.

Comment: sum playcount, group by name, order by playcount. Pretty basic SQL if you're willing to read the manuals.

Comment: Won't get me all four rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a horriblely formated (and probably buggy LoL) query  that should do what you need. Welcome anyone to provide feedback to improve it.

```
INSERT INTO top20 (name, cc, platform, playcount, date) 
SELECT 
    Name, 
    cc,
    Platform,
    Playcount,
    date
FROM
(SELECT 
    m.Name, 
    m.cc,
    m.Platform,
    m.Playcount,
    m.date,
    m2.TotalPlayCount 
FROM Movies m
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        Name, 
        SUM(Playcount) as TotalPlayCount 
    FROM Movies 
    GROUP BY Name 
    ORDER BY TotalPlayCount DESC 
    LIMIT 20) as m2
USING (Name)
ORDER BY TotalPlayCount DESC, Name, cc, Platform) as temp
-- if the final inserted data is not in the order you want, add more ORDER clause here
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a group by in combination with an order by?

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    SUM(Playcount) as TotalPlayCount 
FROM Movies 
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY TotalPlayCount DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

This then can be used to add in into a new table

```
INSERT INTO Statistics (Name, Playcount) 
SELECT 
    Name, 
    SUM(Playcount) as TotalPlayCount 
FROM Movies 
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY TotalPlayCount DESC
```

Comment: I think you are going the right direction but I believe OP wants to show all 4 rows per movie in the final table. If you use SUM and group by name in the first query you'll end up with a table of 20 entries instead of 80.

Comment: Exactly what @JackyCheng said. I need the corresponding 4 rows.